# foreach loop doesn't continue to execute

Tags: php, foreach

I have a code that removes only the xml tags that expired and list the other tags, but if one tag expired it will delete it and stop the foreach loop execution without listing the other tags. if I reload the page after the code finished removing the expired tag it will list the other tags normally without any problem. how can I make it continue to list the other tags?
**php code:**

```
$xml_file = simplexml_load_file("xml_file.xml");
            foreach ($xml_file as $item)
                {
                    $current_date = time();
                    $article_date = (int)$item->date;
                    $item_number = (int)str_replace("a" , "" ,$item->getName());
                    if ($current_date >= $article_date + 100000)
                        {
                            if ($item->children()->getName() == "a")
                                {
                                    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($item);
                                    $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
                                    $return = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
                                    $xml_file->asXML('xml_file.xml');
                                    unlink('file.html');
                                }
                        }
                    elseif ($current_date < $article_date + 100000)
                        {
                            echo 'hello';
                        }
                }
```

**xml code:**

```
<articles>
<a1><a>gr</a><date>14</date></a1>
<a2><a>gr</a><date>1414141414141414</date></a2>
<a3><a>gr</a><date>1414141414141414</date></a3></articles>
```

this code should remove the first tag and print hello twice, but it just removes the first tag and stop the foreach loop execution without printing any thing, and if I reload the page after deleting the first tag it prints hello twice without any problem.

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Comment: @helion3 no error logs.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what each method is doing, but it seems like `$xml_file->asXML('xml_file.xml');` is writing to the same file you're reading in the first line and then iterating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some lines are commented as their purpose is unclear ... You can remove, but not with `foreach` loop and you have to start from the end... otherwise it is like removing the chair under yourself - loop is unclear, whether it should start with the 'new' $item, or jump over it.

```
$children = $xml_file->children(); 
for($i = count($children) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
{ 
  $item = $children[$i];
  $current_date = time();
  $article_date = (int)$item->date;
  $item_number = (int)str_replace("a" , "" ,$item->getName());
  if ($current_date >= $article_date + 100000)
  {
     if ($item->children()->getName() == "a")
     {
       $dom = dom_import_simplexml($item);
       $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
      //  $return = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
      //  $xml_file->asXML('xml_file.xml');
      //  unlink('file.html');
     }
  }
  elseif ($current_date < $article_date + 100000)
  {
     echo 'hello';
  }
}

var_dump($xml_file);
```

Another way to remove child without conversion to DOM is

```
$children = &$xml_file->children();
// the rest is the same, but replace
// $dom = dom_import_simplexml($item);
// $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
// with
unset($children[$i]);
```

Comment: simplexml_import_dom($dom) should convert dom object back to simplexml opbject. xml_file->asXML('xml_file.xml') should save the current simplexml object to xml_file.xml  after removing the first tag, I want to remove the first tag not just from the current simplexml object but also from the xml file. unlink('file.html') is to remove an html file after removing the first tag from xml file I don't think it's related to the question I just wanted to mention it because it may be the reason for the problem. anyway replacing foreach loop with for loop solved the problem. thanks.